# Adding an action to a rails scaffold class from index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a new todo object with

```
rails g scaffold todo title:string commplete:boolean
```

And want to add an action to the index to complete a todo with one click.

So I created an `action complete` on the `todos` controller and then add the following to the `index page`.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Complete', complete_todo_path(todo) %></td>
```

While this is the same as the edit command it will not work.

I just get `undefined method complete_todo_path`

Why does edit work, but the new method does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
resources :todos do
  member do
    get :complete
  end
end
```

You have edit to your `routes.rb` file as above.

**Note:** add `complete` action to `before_action :set_todo` to access the `todo object` in complete action view file

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea on why this worked. Do you have a link for a good resource on routing?

Comment: Yes, [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) the official `rails routes` documentation. Hope it will hep you to get the idea of `rails routes`